# How to implement masked array fitting using lmfit (prior using sigma option of curve_fit)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy-optimize, lmfit, masked-array

I am trying to implement masked-array fitting using `lmfit`.
Prior I was using `curve_fit` using the following code snippet. I have omitted the `def spec` due to its line length. Essentially `def spec` is function that performs  50 interpolations of templates.

Both the observation data and templates have the file structure `x=wavelength`, `y=flux` from `x=500` to `x=550nm`.

The observation data is a mixtures of two spectra with each spectrum have different parameters.

The file `lambda_input` is a list of wavelengths (example: list of wavelengths[1]) to be used in the fitting process. The fit is only to be carried out in these wavelength ranges (+/- line-widths (`lw`))

Using `sigma=weight` works but now I need to use `lmfit` I am struggling to find a method that works.

How can I mask both the observation and templates wavelengths to `input_lambda` in order to use `lmfit`?

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import lmfit

i_run = pd.read_csv("run.txt",delimiter='\t')
i_run.columns = ["wave","flux"]
run_w = np.array(i_run['wave'])
run_f = np.array(i_run['flux']) # observation data

lambda_input = pd.read_excel("../lambda/weights.xlsx") #fitting wavelengths

v1 = 5 # conversion factors
v2 = 6
lw = 0.01 # linewidths (+/- fitting wavelength)

weight = np.zeros(len(run_w)) 
for w in range (0,187):
    n = lambda_input.iat[w,1]
    weight += np.select([np.logical_and(run_w >= ((n *(1 + (v1)))-lw),run_w <= ((n *(1 + (v1)))+lw)),run_w>0],[1,0])
for w in range (0,187):
    n = lambda_input.iat[w,1]
    weight += np.select([np.logical_and(run_w >= ((n *(1 + (v2)))-lw),run_w <= ((n *(1 + (v2)))+lw)),run_w>0],[1,0])
weight = np.select([weight>0,weight==0],[1,1e6])

p1 = 750
p2 = 800
p3 = 1.0
p4 = 20.0
p5 = 30.0
p6 = 0.5
p7 = 0.5
p8 = 100
p9 = -100
p10 = 4.0
p11 = 4.0
p12 = 3.0
p13 = 3.0

def spec(run_w,t1,t2,r,v1,v2,m1,m2,r1,r2,l1,l2,mi1,mi2):

    return spectrum

popt, pcov = curve_fit(spec, xdata=run_w,sigma=weight,ydata=run_f, p0=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13])

model = lmfit.Model(spec) #fitting: lmfit
p = model.make_params(t1=p1,t2=p2,r=p3,v1=p4,v2=p5,m1=p6,m2=p7,r1=p8,r2=p9,l1=p10,l2=p11,mi1=p12,mi2=p13)
fit = model.fit(data=run_f, params=p, run_w=run_w, method='nelder', nan_policy='omit')
lmfit.report_fit(fit)
fit.plot()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wAb2.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `lmfit.Model`, weighting the elements of the data array is done with the `weights` to the `lmfit.Model.fit()` method, to modify the quantity to be minimized in the least-squares sense from `data-model` to `weights*(data-model)`.  See https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#lmfit.model.ModelResult.fit

Ironically, you have a `weight` array, but use this as `sigma` in `curve_fit.  To use with` lmfit.Model.fit()`, you would want to use` 1.0/weight`, or modify your` weight` to something like:

```
weight = np.select([weight>0,weight==0],[1,1.e6])
```

and then use with

```
fit = model.fit(data=run_f, params=p, run_w=run_w, 
                weights=weight, method='nelder', nan_policy='omit')
lmfit.report_fit(fit)
```

I would make a couple more suggestions:

1. don't use `method='nelder'` as the fitting method unless you know
   you need that (and if, then ask yourself why you didn't use that with
   `curve_fit`).  The default fitting method is *highly* recommended, especially to start.
2. If your data has NaNs or Infs, it is way better to remove them before doing the fit than relying on `nan_policy`. If your model generates NaNs or Infs, `nan_policy` won't help at all - those would have to be checked for and resolved.
3. a really key feature of `lmfit.Model` is that parameters are named so as to be meaningful to the person running and interpreting the results.  Having 13 parameters with names like `t1`, `t2,` v1`,` v2`,` m1`,` m2`, etc is going to be hard to interpret in the future.  Names like "time1", "theta1", "velo1", "mass1", "mean1", etc will be much clearer.